# MediaWiki and GraphViz - no charts

Tags: mediawiki, graphviz

OK, so I am trying to get GraphViz working on a MediaWiki installation. I am using Windows 2012 R2 with WAMPserver.

I have installed GraphViz on my C drive, WAMP is on a D drive.

I have added the GraphViz extension as advised on the GraphViz page and changed the settings folder to point to my GraphViz installation. This is what I have in my settings file:

```
    public $createCategoryPages;
    /**      * Constructor for setting configuration variable defaults.      */
    public function __construct() {         // Set execution path       if (
    stristr( PHP_OS, 'WIN' ) && !stristr( PHP_OS, 'Darwin' ) ) {
            $this->execPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GraphViz\bin';        } else           
 {
    $this->execPath = '/usr/bin/';      } 
    $this->mscgenPath = ;       $this->defaultImageType = 'png';
    $this->createCategoryPages = 'no';  } }
```

But when I insert the GraphViz code, for example:

```
=== Example 1 from http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GraphViz ===            
<graphviz border='frame' format='png' desc='none'> digraph example1 {Hello-
>"World!"} 
</graphviz>
```

It doesn't show anything. Anyone know what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how extensions are configured. You shouldn't have any constructor or class definitions in your `LocalSettings.php`.

Do you get any error messages? Make sure you've got things [set up for debugging](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug).

You probably want something like:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'GraphViz' );
$wgGraphVizSettings->execPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GraphViz\bin';
```

Comment: I tried to add that to the local settings, but when I do that I get an error:

"Warning: Creating default object from empty value in D:\wamp64\www\LocalSettings.php on line 194"

Thats the line that call the execPath.

I then get a table for a call back, but it doesn't display well on here.

Comment: Good point! It seems that this is a regression. Tracked in https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T207680 Sorry!